# Add a "Press any key to continue" in VimL?

Tags: vimscript

In an unusual state, I want to ensure that a user sees a warning message upon startup, and presses a key to continue.

I could use `sleep <seconds>`, but I'm sure that `vim` can do this. Go vim!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `input` function, e.g.

```
call input('Press any key to continue')
```

See [`:h input()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#input()).

Comment: To add to your answer, you could also do `inputdialog('Press any key to continue')` for GUI.

Comment: Close. You've implemented "Press **enter** to continue". Not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: True. Sorry, I was a little bit too quick here. I think @IngoKarkat's answer is then more correct, in particular with the `getchar()` function. I could update my answer, but I think it is more fair to mark Ingo's answer as correct.

Answer (score 11):

- For a confirmation, I would use `:call confirm('My warning here')`; this uses a popup window in GVIM.
- To wait for *any* character, you can use `:call getchar()`.
- For a confirmation with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the already mentioned `:call input('Press enter to continue')`

Many people would consider such mandatory interrupt bad user experience. I don't know about your exact use case, but in general, I would just `:autocmd VimEnter * echoerr 'Houston, we have a problem'`. If the user somehow didn't see the message, `:messages` will recall them.